# Git "discrepancy": `git diff` does not take commit messages into consideration but SHA-1 generation takes commit messages while computing SHA-1

Tags: git

I have two git branches `b'` and `b"` with exactly same `SHA-1` and hence contents. I commit `b'` and on commit, instead of `merge` or `rebase` I apply `cherry-pick` with `-x` option of that single commit to my `b"`.

What happens is my commit message for `b"` has a line stating about `cherry-pick` being applied. This is the only difference between my 2 branches. As a result, `SHA-1`s for `b'` and `b"` are different. However, if I `diff` both branches there are no changes.

It is easy to look up `SHA-1` and conclude that the branches are identical instead of `diff`ing branches to determine

I wonder why `git` is not "consistent" as in `git` should perhaps have excluded commit messages from being included while computing `SHA-1` or `git diff` should compare and contrast commit messages?

Comment: @Izkata thanks for this. I have gone through this thread and I know that `git diff` doesn't take into account  `commit-message`. What I am curious and trying to understand is: what could have been a compelling reason to have exclude `git` commit message from `git diff`?. From one of answers in your post, I surely see that you can hack to have "consistent" `SHA-1` and `diff`...but why isn't it a default setting is my question?

Comment: By timestamps do you mean...`cherry-pick` applied altered the time-stamp?

Comment: git keeps track of a lot of metadata, including (if I remember correctly) when the commit was created vs when it was applied, and cherry-pick will change the second one to "now".  (Under normal circumstances, that is `git commit`, the two timestamps will be the same)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to explain!..ok I agree cherry-pick altered timestamp. My question still remains :-). Let me try to ask in a different way:  If SHA-1 not same then git diff also shows metadata discrepancy (User can see diff results and be least concerned if discrepancy is only from metadata) `OR` SHA-1 only computes files "that matter" not metadata and so does `git diff`...why not one of these two approaches?...why SHA-1 considers metadata and git diff does not?...any ideas.

Comment: Questions about toolsets and their intricacies are better answered on StackOverflow.

Comment: git should have a sha for the metadata, and a sha for the diff ... separately

Answer (score 3):

`git diff` is about the changes in actual content and not the meta data. Consider the use case where a commit was cherry picked from another branch. Many a times, you want to know if the same content is there in both the branches, and not if both branches have the same commit. That is where `git diff` comes into the picture.

The commit hashes are of course for commits, and will take the metadata into consideration.

The actual way to see difference in two branches IS `git diff`. If two branches have the same hash for their heads, they do have same content. But if they don't, they need not necessarily have different content.

You might also look at `git log -p` command to see if it suites your purpose.

Comment: thanks for your answer...I understand the "how" part. I was curious of the "why" part. If you look through the comments in my question I have tried to put my question across in different ways. Repeating myself: why SHA-1 considers metadata and git diff does not?...if git diff explicitly had a flag like `--consider-metadata=true/false`. Is there any strong design reason to not consider metadata while diffing?

Answer (score 2):

> I have two git branches b' and b" with exactly same SHA-1 and hence contents.

If b' and b" have the same SHA they are the same commit and b' and b" have the same head.  To understand what is hashed into a commit try:

```
git cat-file commit HEAD
```

giving you the contents of the commit object:

```
tree f8156a51641da281e48960d846857aebc3e784a2
parent 61822c28ea4f8580dda88f3b375aef4e3a4f979b
author Someone <someone@somewhere.com> 1348177711 +0100
committer Someone <someone@somewhere.com> 1348178095 +0100

message
```

You might think in this case you might be able to use the tree hash to determine whether content is the same. This isn't reliable as if some of the changes have already been performed on the branch the tree will be different but the result the content correct.

Why is the commit metadata not included in the diff?  Well one good reason is that the diff doesn't always run on with commits.  It could be comparing content in other forms like the index with a commit so it's orientated around comparing the content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I learned a new command git command :)